# Spring Boot Data JpaSpecificationExecutor couldn't retrieve data by date time

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa

This is my entity class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHECKS")
public class ChecksEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime beginDate;
    private Long checkId;
    private String courtName;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private LocalDateTime decisionDate;
    private String decisionNumber;
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
    private String filePath;
    private String judgeName;
    private String name;
    private String note;
    private String patronymic;
    private String person;
    private String personType;
    private String responseData;
    private String surname;
}
```

and this is my JpaSpecificationExecutor class:

```
@Component
public class ChecksSpecification {

    public Specification<ChecksEntity> getChecks(ArchiveOperationRequestDto request) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (request.getPerson() != null && !request.getPerson().isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("person"), request.getPerson()));
            }
            if (request.getDecisionNumber() != null && !request.getDecisionNumber().isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("decisionNumber"), request.getDecisionNumber()));
            }
            if (request.getCourtName() != null && !request.getCourtName().isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("courtName"), request.getCourtName()));
            }
            if (request.getToDate() != null || request.getFromDate() != null) {
//                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("beginDate"), request.getToDate()));
//                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("beginDate"), request.getFromDate()));
                final Predicate created = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("beginDate"), request.getToDate());
                return criteriaBuilder.or(created);
            }

            return criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }
}
```

When I send a request here, it returns data as normal in response, according to all the values I have specified.

This is my send request dto:

```
@Data
public class ArchiveOperationRequestDto {
    private String person;
    private String decisionNumber;
    private LocalDateTime toDate;
    private LocalDateTime fromDate;
    private String courtName;
}
```

It just doesn't return data about toDate and fromDate. It comes empty. What should I do to return data from database by date?